# PHP Regexp: drop leading zeros from the end of value after decimal

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression such that if a number have decimal point then the zeros (0) at the end must be removed.

Example:

```
$value = 234.8076000
```

**After Regexp Replace it should become**

```
234.8076
```

I am trying the following regexp **[0]+$** in preg_replace but the problem is that if the value does not have decimal point and it contain zero at the end then that zero is also removed.

Example:

```
$value = 2340
```

**It becomes 234 but it should remain 2340**

Any idea? Is there any in-built function in php that can do this?

Comment: @vp-arth It does not detect this value: 2340.0340 Must convert it to 2340.034

Comment: _Number_ 234.807600 doesn't have any trailing zeroes; _String_ does, however. So I really wonder what's wrong with casting that in `float` then (with `(float) $value`).

Comment: @raina77ow - you should write this as an answer. It's really the simplest way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without regexpes:

```
php > echo ((float)"21.40200")."\n";
21.402
```

`/(\.\d*?)0+$/`, works except `/\d+\.0{n}/` cases

Comment: Try your `preg_replace` against `21.00200`.

Comment: php > echo preg_replace("/(\.\d*?)0+$/",'$1',"21.00200")."\n";
21.002

Comment: `echo preg_replace('/(\.\d*?)0+$/','$1','2340.0'); // 2340.`

Comment: It's 21 on my system, not 21.002.  No idea why :)

Comment: @raina77ow These expressions are working fine But in your expample it leaves the decimal if the value is 23.0 Can it also be corrected using  regexp

Comment: If you don't want the decimal part in `23.0`, `float` is really the answer, not the regex.

Comment: Use third "regularexpression". It's perfect!

Comment: After testing it appears that I must use (float)$value. I entered 23.0 and it returned 23 that is correct. The regular expression in this case does not remove decimal point. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you really can do it with regex:

```
$pattern = '/(\.\d*[^0])0+$/';
echo preg_replace($pattern, '$1', '2340'); // 2340
echo preg_replace($pattern, '$1', '2340.0'); // 2340.0
echo preg_replace($pattern, '$1', '2340.07600'); // 2340.076
```

... but the simplest way is just convert a `string` value into a `float` value.

```
echo (float)'2340';       // 2340
echo (float)'2340.0';     // 2340
echo (float)'2340.07600'; // 2340.076
```

Echoing floats that are really integer values drops the decimal part apparently - but it seems from your comments it's actually what you want.